# Linear Algebra Prerequisite for Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, self-learning

It has been a few years since I took my linear algebra course in my undergraduate and next semester I will be taking functional analysis. I am aware of the prerequisite for linear algebra and plan to do a quick review of it before the classes start. I am wondering what topics in linear algebra would be critical to review before learning functional analysis? Are there any good resources that you would recommend to brush up on the materials required?

Comment: Not to be facetious, but... all of it?  :)  It may be particularly helpful to review from materials that do not emphasize matrix-theoretic approaches, because many matrix techniques do not generalize to the infinite-dimensional spaces of interest to functional analysis (while non-matrix-theoretic arguments sometimes still work).  Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* is a good resource of this type.  (Its is often expressly limited to finite dimensional spaces, but its arguments avoid matrix-based reasoning and some of them generalize immediately to at least some classes of operators.)

Comment: The person to ask is the person who will be teaching the course you are planning to take (or someone else in the department who has taught the course there).

Comment: @leslietownes Thanks for the recommendation! I will check the book out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Came to reinforce the "Linear Algebra Done Right".   Functional Analysis generalizes Linear Algebra to the infinite dimensional, where things can get a lot weirder.   The ways of thinking of things as linear operators as not matrices are what is critical

Comment: It is probably more important to review the material in the first course on analysis.